# Firebase Auth SendEmailVerificationAsync fails on recipient email

Tags: firebase, email, unity-game-engine, authentication, email-verification

Trying out Firebase Auth in Unity with email & pass method. User creation works great, I can see the users in Firebase console, and sign in works too. Upon successful account creation I call `SendEmailVerificationAsync()` and it produces error `The email corresponding to this action failed to send as the provided recipient email address is invalid.` while the newly created account actually has valid email without a doubt.

Could someone please advise how to troubleshoot the issue further?

Firebase Unity SDK 6.15.2
Unity version 2019.4.3f1

Comment: If you think that the error message is incorrect, then I suggest contacting Firebase support for help.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down the root cause which was zero width space character at the end of email and password strings when creating the accounts. This was caught when viewing the HTML source of the Firebase dashboard for the email addresses that got registered from Unity app.

Answer (score 1):

You probably use `TMP_Text` child element of `TMP_InputField`. Do it no more as it is the cause for this unfortunate situation. I spent last 2 hours on finding the solution to the problem. Just use `TMP_InputField` (to be strict, its `text` property) and not `TMP_Text`'s one and you'll be fine.